# Where are static variables stored in asp.net aspx page

Tags: asp.net, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are static variables stored in asp.net aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559529/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-asp-net-aspx-page)

Hi can someone please tell me where the static variables are stored in asp.net aspx page.

Is it in the view state? If so I guess you wouldn't want to stored big complex objects?

Comment: Yes, I would like to delete this one.

Comment: why not click the delete button on your question?

Comment: @Kelsey, I'm not sure I have permissions to do that. Where is it?

Comment: I belive you always have permission to delete your own questions - you should find a button just underneath the question tags.

Comment: @Kragen, there only seems to be link, edit and flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables will be stored in the `AppDomain` as part of the state of the type itself. This state willl be **cleared** everytime process gets recycled.